# how to convert a string path from '\' to '/' or '\\'?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to print a Windows-style path which contains `'\'` programmatically. We would be using this string to list all the files recursively in that directory. This issue arises only because I'm reading the string from a Macro set on a remote build server, where it seems the Macro path is setup with `'\'`. The resulting string however is not usable in C++ because any characters after the `'\'` is a special character.

Backstory:
I have an issue with incompatibility from building a project on my machine vs a build server that may have different macros for some include directories. I would like to print the content of a directory defined by a project macro, e.g. `$(OpenCVDir)`. Let's say the `$(OpenCVDir)` is defined as `"c:\opencv"` on this machine.

One way I've found to do this is to define in a preprocessor command `OPENCVDIR=$(OpenCVDir)`, then in my code, print it out as it if was defined in a `#define`, e.g.

```
std::cout<< OPENCVDIR;
```

The problem is that this directory is using Windows-style `'\'` as separator, so it thinks all the separators are special characters and fails.

Is there a way to convert a path which uses `'\'` as separator correctly into either path with `'/'` or `'\\'`?

Comment: The difference between ```\``` and ```\\``` only applies at compile-time, not at runtime.  [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) are only processed in [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). If the string in question is in a compile-time preprocessor macro, you could try wrapping it in `R"(...)"` to make it a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to disable processing of escape sequences.

Comment: You're correct, I get a compile-time error for how 'o' is an unrecognized escape character. As this is on a build system I do not have access to, I'm not able to wrap the macro in R"()". Is there a way to convert them to my preferred type and have it pass compilation?

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you meant:
in the preprocessor command, I would wrap it in the R"()". This works, compiles, and I'm able to manipulate it later.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [make_preferred](http://%20https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-make_preferred) from boost

and then

```
boost::filesystem::path slash("/");
boost::filesystem::path::string_type preferredSlash = slash.make_preferred().native();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As Remy pointed out, because the Macro is used at compile time, it shows a warning so we don't even get to run these functions on the string. Any way to pre-format the string?

Answer (score 0):

Combining answers from both Remy and ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ,

1. in a preprocessor command, define `OPENCVDIR=R"($OpenCVDir)"` such that the `'\'` are taken literally rather than using the escape characters. The string will actually be `"c:\\opencv"` once it gets into execution.
2. (optional) use boost to convert explicitly to `'\\'` or `'/'`

   ```cpp
   boost::filesystem::path slash(OPENCVDIR);
   boost::filesystem::path::string_type preferredSlash = slash.make_preferred().native();
   ```